# Amazon homeskill account linking with IdentityServer4

Tags: amazon-web-services, oauth, alexa-skills-kit

I've been tasked with creating a homeskill for Alexa and the final piece of the puzzle is account linking.

Whilst I was testing the skill I configured the linking following [this](https://www.whizzy.org/2016/12/howto-add-oauth-to-your-alexa-smart-home-skill-in-10-minutes/) tutorial which worked fine. Another developer was tasked with the configuration of our OAuth server which is [IdenityServer4](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/).

When we switched over the configuration in the skill to use our OAuth server and attempted to complete account linking Amazon just returned us to the generic an error occurred page after our auth server successfully generated a ticket.

There's no information given to the reason and the requests look identical to the ones when we were using the Amazon auth server.

I've asked for help on the [Amazon Developer Forum](https://forums.developer.amazon.com/questions/88774/identity-server-4-account-linking-error.html) but so far, (48 hours later) we have yet to get any sort of response. We're all pretty nervous as we are supposed to demoing this next Tuesday.

Has anyone got any clues as to why or ideas how to debug this?

[image]

**UPDATE**

I have just set-up the auth server locally and exposed it using ngrok and got account linking working. So the only differences are the SSL certificate and a load balancer. I'm going to attempt to narrow it down further.

Answer (score 0):

I contacted our support about our SSL certificate and now account linking is working :)